# Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate RTM. Can it be update?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I was given a copy of Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate RTM for trial. Can it be updated? THat is, can I run updates that have been released since my copy was distributed? Thank you.

Comment: When you say 'for trial' you mean [the 90-day trial download](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/try)? What updates do you mean - just the service pack, the feature pack, or something else?

Answer (score 1):

RTM is final, so yes updates will work fine - assuming you mean service packs etc